# MS Graph API add permission to File

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-files

I am using MS graph API to add document to one drive and give permission to other user. I have followed this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-invite?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to add permission which works as expected. All of a sudden its worked in a different way, instead of grant access to the user it generates a link for the same user. Anyone have any idea how to fix this. Please find the code below and generated output.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please try using the MSA account for emailaddress. I have given a try with the user in my tenant as email and it worked for me.

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: no the issue was different

Comment: Is the problem resolved?